# Conditions for a locally integrable function to induce a tempered distribution

Tags: distribution-theory, schwartz-space

I've come across a statement in my book, that I think the author expected to be obvious so I feel like I'm missing something rather trivial here.

Suppose $f \in L_\text{loc}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$.  If $$\int_{|x| \leq A} |f(x)| \ dx \leq cA^N $$  , for some constants $c$ and $N$, then for any $\psi \in S(\mathbb R^n)$, we have that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f(x)\psi(x)| \ dx < \infty$$ where $S(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is of course the Schwartz Class.  Moreover, we have that this condition is necessary if $f$ is positive.

I don't see why this is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $l\geqslant 1$, let $E_l:=\left\{x\in\mathbb R^n,l\lt  \lVert x\rVert \leqslant l+1\right\}$ and let $M:=\sup_{x\in\mathbb R^n}\lVert x\rVert^{N+2}\left\lvert\phi(x)\right\rvert $. Then 
 $$\int_{E_l}|f(x)\psi(x)| \mathrm dx=\int_{E_l}\lvert f(x)\rvert\underbrace{    \lvert   \psi(x)\rvert  \lVert x\rVert^{N+2}}_{\leqslant M}     \cdot \underbrace{\lVert x\rVert^{-N-2}}_{\leqslant l^{-N-2}}           \mathrm dx\leqslant Mc\frac{(l+1)^N}{l^{N+2}}.                  $$
This proves that the series $\sum_l \int_{E_l}|f(x)\psi(x)| \mathrm dx$ converges hence $\int_{\bigcup_l E_l}|f(x)\psi(x)|\mathrm dx $ converges.

Comment: Hi Davide, can you elaborate on the convergence of the series $\sum_l Mc\frac{(l+1)^N}{l^{N+2}}$? I tried to use the ratio test, but the limit of the ratio is $1$. And so I can't conclude it is convergent.

Comment: Bound $(l+1)^N$ by $2^Nl^N$ and use the convergence of $\sum_l l^{-2}$.